# Bubble sort confusion in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist, bubble-sort

I have a question about bubble sort using an array. Here is some example code:

```
public class SortArray 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = {4,6,4,2,764,23,23};
        sort(arr);
    }
    static void sort(int[] arr)
    {
        int k;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i; j < arr.length-1; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i] < arr[j+1])
                {
                    k = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = k;
                }
            }
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }   
    }
}
```

There are two loops for checking the array, I understand the first loop is to go through each element in array, but how about the second one? Why is `j` starting from `i` and why is it going up to the length minus 1?

Additionally, can I use bubble sort to sort an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is called [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), not [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Bubble sort only swaps adjacent elements, but you're going though the rest of the array and finding the minimum, which is exactly what selection sort does.

Since you use `arr[j+1]`, you can rewrite the inner loop to use `arr[j]` and shift up the range by one, like this:

```
for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
{
    if(arr[i] < arr[j])
    {
        k = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = k;
    }
}
```

Now it's a bit more clear that you're looking at each other remaining element to find the minimum.

Yes, you can modify any sort that works on arrays to sort an `ArrayList` instead by just using `ArrayList.get` instead of array accesses and `ArrayList.set` instead of array assignments, i.e.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); j++)
    {
        if(arr.get(i) < arr.get(j))
        {
            int k = arr.get(j);
            arr.set(j, arr.get(i));
            arr.set(i, k);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that both selection sort and bubble sort are fairly inefficient (`O(n^2)`), [there are more efficient sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) such as quick-sort or merge-sort (running in `O(n log n)`).

Answer (score 0):

The first loop holds an element in `i` and the second one examines each element after `i`, namely `j` and compares it to the `i` it has holded. If they can be swapped, the algorithm swaps their positions and moves on. When the outer loop finishes an iteration, all elements prior to `i` are sorted, so `j` starts from `i`.

Do this once on paper and it all makes sense.

*EDIT*: As you have completed your algorithm, the reason for the second loops condition, is that you swap `i` with `j+1`. So if your `j` goes on to the last element of the array, the next element wouldn't exist and raises an exception. Also you can use this code to sort `ArrayList`. Just change the code swapping values with the appropriate setters and getters.

Comment: In addition I would offer you to use another sort, this sort is slow and low performance. The good sorts are Quick Sort and Merge Sort.